# What do the orange keys do?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

I just found an orange key that went on top of my key count. What does this item/pickup do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orange key makes it so that when you open something that requires a key, you do not use up one of your keys. It disappears when you go to the next level.